# Wordpress if is page and in category question

Tags: php, wordpress, conditional-statements

I can't seem to find an answer to this question anywhere, so I'm wondering if anyone might be able to help?

How do I combine the is_page and in_category clause?

At the moment, home-2 (the slug) doesn't seem to want to work.

```
<?php if(is_page( 'Home' )) { ?>

    <?php } elseif (is_page('home-2')) { ?>

<?php } elseif (in_category('projects')) { ?>

<?php } else { ?>

<?php } ?>
```

Thanks.

Comment: please explain more. as I understand you need an if condition like this :`(is_page('home-2') || in_category('projects'))` ?

Comment: @Seymour Did any of the proposed answer solve your problem? If so, please feel free to mark any of them as accepted answers.

Answer (score 0):

In Condition '&&' is 'AND' and '||' is 'OR'.
Use this and combine many clause.

```
if(is_page('home-2') && in_category('projects')){
                  OR
if(is_page('home-2') || in_category('projects')){
    //Your Statement here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to combine conditions in an `if`-clause you can either join them with `&&` (evaluates as *and*) or `||` (evaluates as *or*).

```php
if (cond1 && cond2) // Will only be true if both cond1 and cond2 is true.
if (cond1 || cond2) // Will be true if either of cond1 or  cond2 is true.
```

This code should be sufficient for your solution:

```php
<?php if(is_page('Home')) { ?>
    <!-- You're on page Home -->
<?php } elseif (is_page('home-2') && in_category('projects')) { ?>
    <!-- You're on page home-2 in category projects -->
<?php } else { ?>
    <!-- You're somewhere else -->
<?php } ?>
```